# Combinations Equation to prove (possibly with Pascal's relation?)

Tags: binomial-coefficients, combinations

Can this equation be proved?

$${n \choose p} = {n-2 \choose p} + 2 {n-2 \choose p-1} + {n-2 \choose p-2}$$

Here is what I've tried:

$${ 
   {n!\over (n - p)! p!} = {(n - 2)! \over (n - p -2)! p!} + {2(n - 2)!\over (n-p-1)! (p - 1)!} + {(n-2)!\over(n-p)!(p-2)!}
   }$$
Then trying to get the common denominator:

$${
   {n!\over (n - p)! p!} = {(n - 2)! \over (n-p-2)!p(p-1)(p-2)!} + {2(n - 2)!\over (n-p-1)(n-p-2)!(p-1)(p-2)!} + {(n - 2)! \over (n-p)(n-p-1)(n-p-2)!(p-2)!}
   }$$

Then:

$${
{n!} = (n-p)(n-p-1)(n-2)!+2p(n-p)(n-2)!+p(p-1)(n-2)!
}$$

factorizing this gets me:

$${
{n!} = (n-2)![(n-p)(n-3p-1)+p(p-1)]
}$$

and that's it.

Comment: I have tried expanding both sides, and taking a common denominator in the right side. Eventually I reach this: n! = (n-2)! [n^2 -4pn -n + 4p^2]

Comment: If you just apply Pascal's rule twice, you should get the result.

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Try $n=3, p=2$. LHS is 3 but the RHS is $1+2\times 1 + 1 = 4$

Comment: I think there shouldn't be a 2 in front of the second term of the left hand side.

Comment: the identity should be ${n \choose p} = {n-\color{red}{2} \choose p} + 2 {n-2 \choose p-1} + {n-2 \choose p-2}$

Comment: It is -2. Sorry I'll edit that.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the way I've tried. Is there a simple mistake somewhere in it or am I going about this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an algebraic proof, here it comes:

Actually you did everything alright, but you made one mistake, it is

\begin{align}
{n \choose p} &= {n-2 \choose p} + 2 {n-2 \choose p-1} + {n-2 \choose p-2}
\end{align}
which gives you after factorizing (everything good until here)
$$
n! = (n-p)(n-p-1)(n-2)!+2p(n-p)(n-2)!+p(p-1)(n-2)!
$$
Now here comes the mistake, it is not $(n-3p-1)$ but
\begin{align}
n! &= (n-p)(n-p-1)(n-2)!+2p(n-p)(n-2)!+p(p-1)(n-2)!\\
&=(n-2)!\left[(n-p)(n-p-1+2p)+p(p-1)\right]\\
&=(n-2)!\left[(n-p)(n\color{red}{+p-1})+p(p-1)\right]
\end{align}
which goes into
$$
\Leftrightarrow (n-1)n=n^2-n=\left[(n-p)(n+{p-1})+p(p-1)\right]
$$
and this leads you directly to an equality, the $p$'s are cancelling out and you got what you were looking for!

Comment: This kind of mistakes will be the death of me. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I know, sometimes it is really hard to spot them yourself! Personally I find it extremely hard to justify these kind of equalities by using combinatorical arguments as Pablo did. So I feel with you since I would go the same way as you and write everything out - which automatically leads to a lot of mistakes

Answer (score 2):

Combinatorial interpretation:

On the left side, you have all possibilities to choose $p$ elements from set $\{1,2,...,n\}$.

On the right side it is the same because.

You can do a set without $n, n-1$. So you have $\{1,...,n-2\}$.

Now you have two sets $\{n,n-1\}$ and $\{1,...,n-2\}$ and trying to combine elements from two of them to have all $p$ - element subsets of $\{1,2,...,n\}$

1) You choose $p$ elements from set $\{1,...,n-2\}$, so $\binom{n-2}{p}$

2) You choose $p-1$ elements from this set and ADD in TWO possible ways ONE element from $\{n-1,n\}$ so you have $2\binom{n-2}{p-1}$

3) You choose $p-2$ elements from this set and have no other option except to take both $\{n-1,n\}$ to have a set of $p$ elements so $\binom{n-2}{p-2}$.

Cases 1), 2), 3) represent all the possibilities, so you add them and have right side.

Comment: Your english is great actually. I was hoping however for an algebraic proof. I'm currently trying to apply Pascal's rule twice as suggested by one of the commenters.

Comment: OK I didn't know. :) However my solution is exactly doing Pascal rule twice but in combinatorial way. Algebraically this is really simple and I think you will get it fast. I just wrote it because a lot of people use symbols (n k) and proving identities but they don't know what they mean.

Comment: Yes you're right. It worked Algebraically by applying Pascal's Rule twice. Thanks a lot for the combinatorial way.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The identity was proved using Pascal's Rule twice as suggested by @Raskolnikov. Thanks All.